# Eclipse MenuManager: get ImageDescriptor of Image?

Tags: java, image, menu, swt, contextmenu

I cannot get this to work so I thought it might be a wise idea posting over here...

I have a **context menu in SWT** (actually its an Eclipse plugin). It's a cascaded menu, so it expands as soon as you hover over a certain entry...

My problem is, that I want to **attach a small icon to the menu**  but I struggle with that!

Code:
                ....

```
            manager.add(new Separator());

            // icon for the "change color" menu
            ImageDescriptor icon = ImageDescriptor.createFromFile(null,
                "icons/palette_brush.png");

            // submenu
            MenuManager colorMenu = new MenuManager("Menu", icon,  null);

            // Actions
            colorMenu.add(someAction);

            // add the action to the submenu
            manager.add(colorMenu);

           ....
```

My problem is, that the *new MenuManager* can either be called with 2 Arguments (no attached image) or 3 (with attached image). The image should be passed along as ***ImageDescriptor***.

The question basically is:
*"How can I get an Imagedescriptor off an image?"*

Maybe it's an stupid mistake - but I cannot get an ImageDescriptor from an image file. I have an *.png icon ready to use, but I struggle incorporating this.

If anyone could help out with a snippet, that would get me an *ImageDescriptor* from an image file this would be soo awesome!

Best regards!

MenuManager Documentation:
[MenuManager Docu](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/action/MenuManager.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(pluginId);
URL fullPathString = BundleUtility.find(bundle, "icons/palette_brush.png");
ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(fullPathString);
```

`pluginId` is the id of the plugin where you put your icon.

Comment: thanks a lot! This is how i finally did it: ImageDescriptor icon = Bundle                .getImageDescriptor("icons/palette_brush.png");

Answer (score 3):

```
Bundle bundle= org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getBundle(pluginId);
URL fullPathString = bundle.getEntry("icons/palette_brush.png");
desc= ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(fullPathString);
desc.createImage();
```

Comment: This may actually be a helpful answer but it's hard to tell without any context or explanation.